# When to vertically partition a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 100 columns and I know there is an 8k limit before a table overflows in SQL Server

I'm using the following query's to have a look at the table stats

```
dbcc showcontig ('Products') with tableresults
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'tablename'), OBJECT_ID(N'Products'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED'
```

I notice, with the second query as follows:

```
index_type_desc,    alloc_unit_type_desc, page_count
CLUSTERED INDEX,    LOB_DATA            , 2
```

If I am reading it correctly there is only 2 pages of overflow?

```
MinimumRecordSize,  MaximumRecordSize,  AverageRecordSize
628,                7928,               950.048
```

Is there further metrics to say (in a more concise way)? If I really need to go to the extra effort of vertically partitioning this table?

At the moment, it looks like i am no where near the 8k column limit for native column size, and the majority of my data is all `in Row Data`

Is it a fair assumption to say query performance should not be impacted all that much?

P.S.: I know this is a long question, however some good concise metrics would be a good start for me

Comment: LOB_DATA <> row overflow data. This means your table definition has one or more of the following types: deprecated text,ntext or image or varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max) or xml. You see only 2 pages because it's probably varchar(max) and the values were fitted into a row, so there is only IAM page and 1 allocated page of LOB data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider `vertical partitioning` of your table if your columns have different access pattern: some columns are often read and (almost) never updated, others are often updated.

Unless you have `columnstore indexes` or covering indexes for your queries, every time you need only some columns a whole row is retrived, so if you want namy rows but for limited columns `vertical partitioning` may be your case.

Please also take a look on this: [Vertical Partitioning as the way to reduce IO](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/09/15/vertical-partitioning-as-the-way-to-reduce-io/)

Note that `MinimumRecordSize` 628 + `MaximumRecordSize` 7928 means that your rows have fields of variable length data types such as `varchar(max)`, and this means that you did not reach max row size. If `MinimumRecordSize` was equal to `MaximumRecordSize` this could mean that you may will not be able to add othe columns to your table, but since `MinimumRecordSize` is only 628, many other `variable length` columns can still be added.

When row-overfloing data does not fit in a row, a newe page is allocated to accomodate it and only a small pointer is left on original row that points to `row-overflow` page containing the value.